# Android media player doesn't work

Tags: java, android, stream, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to play an alarm sound but I got this error and I can't hear the voice. It doesn't cause any problem in app or crashing, but there is no sound.

```
03-13 00:35:01.138: D/MediaPlayer(2580): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
03-13 00:35:01.138: E/MediaPlayer(2580): Unable to create media player
03-13 00:35:01.138: I/alarmReceiver(2580): No audio file founded!
```

Based on my debugging, this error happens right before this line of code runs:

```
mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, alert);
```

This not only happened in emulator but also in real device; I can't hear anything.

Here is my code:

```
playSound(this, getAlarmUri()); 

private void playSound(Context context, Uri alert) {        
    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();       
    try {           
        mMediaPlayer.reset();
        **mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, alert);**
        final AudioManager am = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        Log.i("getStreamVolume", am.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM)+"");

        if (am.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM) != 0) {
            mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
            mMediaPlayer.prepare();
            mMediaPlayer.start();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Log.i("alarmReceiver", "No audio file founded!");
    }
}

private Uri getAlarmUri()
    {       
        Uri alert=RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
        if(alert==null)
        {
            alert= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri((RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
            if(alert==null)
            {
                alert=RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
            }
        }
        Log.i("alert", alert.toString());
        return alert;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the data source before resetting the media player.
`...
mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, alert);
try
{
    mMediaPlayer.reset();
    ...`

Comment: thank you so much. but it didn't work :(. Actually, I didn't have reset before and I put it there because of one article that I read, did it work for you? any other idea? Thank you

Comment: Do you any other suggestion? Anyone else? Thank you

Comment: Sorry I have not done much with media player yet, but the suggestion I gave worked for me last time I had problems with it. Unfortunately I have no more suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

ok guys I found a solution for my problem.

I created raw folder under my res folder and put my song.mp3 there and

```
mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(); 
    try {
        final AudioManager am = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.song);
        mMediaPlayer.start();


    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (SecurityException e) {

        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {

        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

just don't forget to stop and release the mediapleayr when you are done with it.

```
mMediaPlayer.stop();
mMediaPlayer.release();
```